# Can't use XLabs prerelease packages in appstore builds

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xlabs

I am building an app with Xamarin Forms and XLabs plugins. 
To be able to run everything smoothly on Android and Windows Phone, i've had to use a prerelease version of xlabs (2.2.0-pre05).

When I tried to create a Windows Phone appstore package the certification failed because the packages for 2.2.0-pre05 have been built in debug mode.

To overcome this, I cloned the git hub project for XLabs and built everything in release mode.

The problem is, when I try to build the project with the packages i've built, I get this error:

- Payload file '..\packages\Mike Xlabs\XLabs.Platform.WinRT.Phone\FodyWeavers.xml' does not exist.

Also, the windows store certification checks fail because of libraries used by the prerelease package.I'm getting the following error:

Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:

```
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=D2D1GetGradientMeshInteriorPointsFromCoonsPatch. Module=d2d1.dll. File=SharpDX.Direct2D1.dll.
```

Impact if not fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Phone Store apps violates the Windows Phone Store certification requirements.

Comment: It seems that creating the folder and file requested solves the first problem.